# Firebase: Checking whether a node exists or not

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function which checks whether a node is available or not. The function is as follows

```
public class Utilities {
    static boolean availability;
    static FirebaseDatabase fireDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    static DatabaseReference dbRef1;
    private static boolean checkAvailability(String ID) {
        /**check in firebase if the generated ID exists. if it exists return false, else return true**/
        final String id = ID;
        availability = true;

            dbRef1 = fireDb.getReference("xdsdads");
            dbRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    try {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(id) || dataSnapshot.hasChild("Room:" + id)) {
                            Log.d("key", "Key exists!");
                            availability = false;
                        } else {
                            availability = true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Error", "error getting key" + e.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        Log.d("Availability","" + availability);
        return availability;

    }


    public static String generateID() {
        /**generates ID **/
        String ID = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (i < 4) {
                ID = ID + giveAlphabet(random.nextInt(26));
            } else {
                ID = ID + random.nextInt(9);
            }
        }
        Log.d("ID",ID);

        if (checkAvailability(ID)) {
            return ID;
        } else {
            return generateID();
        }
    }

    public static String giveAlphabet(int i) {
        /**returns an alphabet from A-Z**/
        String[] alphabet = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
        String output = "";
        try {
            if (i >= 0 && i < 26) {
                output = alphabet[i];
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Value not between 0-26 cannot generate Alphabet");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception at Beacon", e.toString());
        }
        return output;
    }
```

here is my json

```
 {
  "PKWC1865" : "77.6709266,12.8541147",
  "QKAR6584" : "79.6944701,11.1072002",
  "Room:ANWE3226" : {
    "FREESLOTS" : "2,3,4",
    "USER1" : "BC:QKAR6584",
    "USER2" : "NONE",
    "USER3" : "NONE",
    "USER4" : "NONE"
  }
}
```

sampledb is my root. I am checking whether the argument ID is present in db or not. But onDataChange method is never called. and hence I could never check whether the given node is present or not.

Comment: That method will always return true. You should make a callback interface and pass it as an argument to your method.

Comment: the variable "availability" is global,

Comment: well generateID will not take into account whether or not your ID exists as it will return instantly with true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing synchronous with asynchronous patterns. Your function will call Firebase for data, but then return immediately before it has an answer. Firebase must call the network to obtain the data, and this takes time. When the answer arrives, it is too late because you have already attempted to return a value.

What you need to do is have your function take a callback as an additional parameter. When the data arrives, call this callback with the value. To do so, you will almost certainly also need to rewrite how you make the call in the first place. If you have designed the upstream logic to expect a synchronous operation here, that upstream logic will also need to be changed to tolerate asynchronous behavior.